# Observer for item in Array controller

Tags: ember.js

I am using Array controller to store some array of items.

Each item has properties **isChecked** (either set to true or false) and value .

My Array controller looks like

```
Application.PlatformsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

contentPropertyFirst: function () {
    return true;
}.property("content.@each.isChecked"),

contentPropertySecond: function () {
    return true;
}.property("content.@each"),                                                                                                           

contentPropertyThird: function () {
    return true;
}.property("content"),

contentObserver: function () {
    return true;
}.observes("content"),

init: function () {
    this.setData();
},

setData: function () {

    Appication.Services.fetch('Data') //returns data from my service.
     .done(function (data) {
         this.get('content').clear();
         $.each(data, function (index, item) {
             this.get('content').pushObject(item);
             this.get('content')[index].isChecked = true;
         });
     })
    .fail(function () {
        alert('Error');
    });
}
```

In another controller I set one of its property to the above controller

```
Application.EditPlatformsController = Application.UI.Controller.extend({
start: function () {
    this.set('listController',Application.PlatformsController.create());
},
```

In my view, i render the check boxes w.r.t to the list of array items available in listController.

```
  {{#each listController}}
  {{view CoreCheckbox checkedBinding="isChecked"}} {{ value  }}
  {{/each }}
```

In the above case only contentObserver method gets called when pushing item to content.

I want to do some action on **check** and **uncheck** operation of **check box**.

Please assist me in doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed properties are dynamically updated when they are called. If you want the observer to fire on change, change "property" to "observes"

```
contentPropertyFirst: function () {
  return true;
}.observes("content.@each.isChecked"),

contentPropertySecond: function () {
  return true;
}.observes("content.@each"),                                                                                                           

contentPropertyThird: function () {
  return true;
}.observes("content"),

contentObserver: function () {
  return true;
}.observes("content"),
```

Comment: Thanks James. I've tried this earlier but don't know why it did not work first time. Any way thanks for your reply.